# How to Open a Modal Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an HTML code which have fab floating button when i click on that button i want to open a modal popup window but I don't know how to do it.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/kc.fab.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Materialize Floating Action Button - jQuery plugin</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Please feel free to use and contribute! :)</h2>
    <div class="kc_fab_wrapper" >

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/kc.fab.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var links = [
                {
                    "bgcolor":"red",
                    "icon":"+"
                },
                {
                    "url":"http://www.example.com",
                    "bgcolor":"red",
                    "color":"#fffff",
                    "icon":"<i class='fa fa-phone'></i>",
                    "target":"_blank"
                },
                {
                    "url":"http://www.example.com",
                    "bgcolor":"black",
                    "color":"white",
                    "icon":"<i class='fa fa-music'></i>"
                }
            ]
            $('.kc_fab_wrapper').kc_fab(links);
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

for more below demo is helpful
http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-Design-Floating-Action-Button-with-jQuery-KC-FAB.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest having a look at http://materializecss.com

**Fiddle example**: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeferrari/a4xhxknk/

Include the script and css file in your index.html page first

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I use this frequently and the documentation and example code is great.
There is an easy to implement example for a modal button here:

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to open modal from fab buttons not parent button but from child button

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? I included a FAB button in the example. Here's a direct link to the FAB buttons on the materializecss website http://materializecss.com/buttons.html#floating. You can make any button open the modal by formatting the href attribute value as <a href="#modal1">

Comment: hey all working properly but when i move cursor to the floating button its doesn't show any effect what to do now please help....

Comment: If the FAB button isn't responding to mouse events, I would suggest reviewing your code. Start from line 1 and see what you've missed.